# how can I insert Comma separated values in multiple column using merge into statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table and contains following fields in my Oracle DB

```
THEME_ID
DIR_ID
CLUSTER_ID
MONTH_ID
```

The Sample output should be like below, I am inserting as multiple row using below `MERGE..INTO` query. Total 12 rows needs to be inserted. As per my query it inserts only 6 because month_id not included as part of query

```
THEME_ID DIR_ID CLUSTER_ID MONTH_ID
23        2       a          1
23        2       c          1
23        2       v          1
23        2       a          2
23        2       c          2 
23        2       v          2
123       2       a          1
123       2       c          1
123       2       v          1
123       2       a          2
123       2       c          2
123       2       v          2
```

I am inserting multiple comma separate values based on THEME_ID

for eg:

```
P_themeId = '23,123'
P_dirId = '2'  ( only one value here always)
P_clusterId = 'a,c,v'
```

The below query works only for `THEME_ID,DIR_ID and CLUSTER_ID`. Now I want to insert `MONTH_ID` . This also contains multiple comma separated value as given in query. `**(P_month varchar2(20) := '1,2';)**` But I am not able to write a query for month part. is it possible to include this in `MERGE INTO` query or some other way

```
 PROCEDURE SP_TEST (
         P_themeId IN VARCHAR2,
        P_dirId IN NUMBER,
        P_clusterId IN VARCHAR2,
        P_createdBy IN VARCHAR2,
     P_ALL OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
    ) AS
    **P_month varchar2(20) := '1,2';**
    BEGIN
     FOR i IN
    (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(P_themeId, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
    FROM dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(P_themeId, ',')+1
    )

    LOOP

     MERGE INTO TBL_TEST TA USING
      (SELECT TMP1.CLUSTERID
      FROM
        (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(P_clusterId, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) CLUSTERID
    FROM dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(P_clusterId, ',')+1 ) TMP1
      ) TMP ON (TA.CLUSTER_ID = TMP.CLUSTERID AND TA.THEME_ID = i.l )
     
      
      
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT
        ( THEME_ID,DIR_ID, CLUSTER_ID,CREATED_BY
        ) VALUES
        ( i.l,P_dirId,TMP.CLUSTERID,P_createdBy
        );

     END LOOP;


       OPEN P_ALL FOR SELECT
                            
                              'INserted' AS msgs
                          FROM
                              dual;

    END SP_TEST;
```

Comment: stating the obvious, why don't you normalize?

Comment: @Randy Should I create another table and insert ?

Comment: Yes, create other tables and normalize the data.  storing lists like that is just going to be a ton of headaches.

Comment: Are you actually trying to store the lists, or convert the lists into multiple rows as part of the insert/update? It would help if you edited your question to include the current and expected results - what you want to end up with in your table, for various example lists. Also do the lists have to be strings, or can they be supplied to your process as collections, which would make things a bit easier?.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have updated expected output in a sample table. IF I make separate table how can I get last insert id from above query

Comment: Not sure what you mean about last insert ID? And I think the previous comments about normalising and using a separate table were based on the assumption you were going to store the CSV values unchanged in your main table. What you are actually doing shouldn't need a separate table. Should your example produce 12 rows instead of 6 - every combination of theme and cluster for every month? If not are the themes and months linked - by position, and if so what if there are different numbers of each?

Comment: @AlexPoole , Yes you are right. I am inserting all the data row by row in a single table. As per my above query I am stuck at month_Id. How to insert month_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a PL/SQL loop (or nested loops), you could do all the unnesting of the lists within the merge statement, using cross-joined subquery factoring (CTEs):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TEST (
    P_themeId IN VARCHAR2,
    P_dirId IN NUMBER,
    P_clusterId IN VARCHAR2,
    P_createdBy IN VARCHAR2,
    P_ALL OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
) AS
    P_month varchar2(20) := '1,2';
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO TBL_TEST ta
    USING
    (
        WITH themes (theme_id) AS (
            SELECT regexp_substr(P_themeId, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1)
            FROM dual
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(P_themeId, ',') + 1
        ),
        clusters (cluster_id) AS (
            SELECT regexp_substr(P_clusterId, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1)
            FROM dual
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(P_clusterId, ',') + 1
        ),
        months (month_id) AS (
            SELECT regexp_substr(P_month, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1)
            FROM dual
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(P_month, ',') + 1
        )
        SELECT t.theme_id, P_dirId as dir_id, c.cluster_id, m.month_id
        FROM themes t
        CROSS JOIN clusters c
        CROSS JOIN months m
    ) tmp
    ON (
        ta.theme_id = tmp.theme_id
        AND ta.dir_id = tmp.dir_id
        AND ta.cluster_id = tmp.cluster_id
        AND ta.month_id = tmp.month_id
    )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (THEME_ID, DIR_ID, CLUSTER_ID, MONTH_ID, CREATED_BY)
    VALUES (tmp.theme_id, tmp.dir_id, tmp.cluster_id, tmp.month_id, P_createdBy);

    OPEN P_ALL FOR SELECT 'INserted' AS msgs FROM dual;
END SP_TEST;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1cb6200673f51ab43184b39cc88fb5c0)

or cross apply or cross--join lateral with inline views:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TEST (
    P_themeId IN VARCHAR2,
    P_dirId IN NUMBER,
    P_clusterId IN VARCHAR2,
    P_createdBy IN VARCHAR2,
    P_ALL OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
) AS
    P_month varchar2(20) := '1,2';
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO TBL_TEST ta
    USING
    (
        SELECT t.theme_id, P_dirId as dir_id, c.cluster_id, m.month_id
        FROM (
            SELECT regexp_substr(P_themeId, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) AS theme_id
            FROM dual
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(P_themeId, ',') + 1
        ) t
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
            SELECT regexp_substr(P_clusterId, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) AS cluster_id
            FROM dual
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(P_clusterId, ',') + 1
        ) c
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
            SELECT regexp_substr(P_month, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) AS month_id
            FROM dual
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(P_month, ',') + 1
        ) m
    ) tmp
    ON (
        ta.theme_id = tmp.theme_id
        AND ta.dir_id = tmp.dir_id
        AND ta.cluster_id = tmp.cluster_id
        AND ta.month_id = tmp.month_id
    )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (THEME_ID, DIR_ID, CLUSTER_ID, MONTH_ID, CREATED_BY)
    VALUES (tmp.theme_id, tmp.dir_id, tmp.cluster_id, tmp.month_id, P_createdBy);

    OPEN P_ALL FOR SELECT 'INserted' AS msgs FROM dual;
END SP_TEST;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bf80a9234cb20e154dc2589a0c99d646)

Either way that generates 12 rows with your sample strings:

| THEME_ID | DIR_ID | CLUSTER_ID | MONTH_ID | CREATED_BY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 2 | a | 1 | someone |
| 23 | 2 | a | 2 | someone |
| 23 | 2 | c | 1 | someone |
| 23 | 2 | c | 2 | someone |
| 23 | 2 | v | 1 | someone |
| 23 | 2 | v | 2 | someone |
| 123 | 2 | a | 1 | someone |
| 123 | 2 | a | 2 | someone |
| 123 | 2 | c | 1 | someone |
| 123 | 2 | c | 2 | someone |
| 123 | 2 | v | 1 | someone |
| 123 | 2 | v | 2 | someone |

You don't really need PL/SQL, but it looks like you want to have a PL/SQL wrapper around the merge.

Comment: it doesn't work for following way declare
  p_all sys_refcursor;
begin
  sp_test('23,121', 2, 'ac,avs', 'someone', p_all);
end;
/

Comment: @atc - [yes it does](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ac89c07cb7bf2525c3a692a439119515) - at least after I increased the maximum size of `cluster_id` from 1 to 3. (You didn't say how your table was defined so I just made it big enough for your example...) What does "doesn't work" mean - what error or wrong result are you getting?

Comment: I fixed that. Just noticed the typo in table.